# How to draw a polygon like google map in android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

I am creating a map app for a place for my city and i want to draw a polygon around that place.
i have a example of my app idea in web google map like this picture: [image]
 How can i do like this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Original documentation has clear explanation for [Polygon API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon).
All that you need to do is use this method with own coordinates and colors:

> ```
> GoogleMap map; 
> // ... get a map. 
> // Add a triangle in the Gulf of Guinea
> Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
>     .add(new LatLng(0, 0), new LatLng(0, 5), new LatLng(3, 5), new LatLng(0, 0))
>     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
>     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
> ```