# How can I implement thematic map in native android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

How can I implement thematic map in native android development for a particular value group like: population, children mortality rate or gender. Is there any library to acheive this, Please let me know.

[image: Here I am attaching snapshot of a thematic map, what i am trying to do.]

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section: Don't ask about...

Comment: I have already searched and found nothing related to this. I asked if any one implemented this type of view, can give reference.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do that:

1) draw [polygons](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon) of thematic map over google maps like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45803711/6950238) question;

2) create [KML](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml) file for custom thematic map and KMLLayer to google map liken in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32351152/6950238) answer;

3) use [Ground Overlay](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay) to overlay google map by image of thematic map;

4) use [TileOverlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay) and create custom tile provider for your thematic map, like in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles) question;

and so on...